# How to use C# to capture a image of a specific url?

Tags: c#, image, url, capture

How to use C# to capture a image of a specific url?

I want to use C# to automatically capture a image of a webpage based on a specific url.

For example, I have a page contains a txtUrl.Text = "http://www.some.com/index.aspx" , then I click a button, how can I capture a image of that Url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to do this from ASP.NET (as opposed to from a WinForms application).

In your web project, add a reference to System.Windows.Forms (yes, this is a bad thing to do).  In your code-behind, you can then create an object of type System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
// this will load up a URL into the web browser:
browser.Navigate(@"http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

Next, just use the BitBlt API function (sorry, I don't have a link handy) to copy the WebBrowser control's graphical display to a Bitmap (which you can then display or save or whatever).  With this function, the WebBrowser's Handle property is one of the parameters to pass.

Update:  here's a link to some code that does exactly what you need:  http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4712/generate-an-image-of-a-web-page/

Comment: I found a code here: http://blog.kurtiswelch.com/post/2009/04/24/Get-Website-Thumbnail-in-C.aspx

And that blog provide a asp.net web interface for generating thumbnails: 
http://kurtiswelch.com/util/DownloadThumbnail.aspx

But how can I use the winform code to implement the same function in   webform just like the: 
http://kurtiswelch.com/util/DownloadThumbnail.aspx

Comment: @Mike:  you can use the winforms code in your web app by adding the reference to System.Windows.Forms - it just isn't a really good idea to do so, especially if this is for a site that will actually get some use.

Comment: The code from:
http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4712/generate-an-image-of-a-web-page/     

works fine for some urls and do not work for other urls.

The code from:
http://www.wincustomize.com/articles.aspx?aid=136426&c=1
works better than above.

Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean a visual of the webpage, one approach is to integrate IE to your application and programmatically taking a screenshot. [This](http://www.alexschultz.co.uk/weblog/2006/05/web_browser_wid.html) (for the integrated web browser) and [this](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial181_Capturing-screenshots-using-Csharp.html) (for taking screenshots with C#) may be of use. This is of course IE dependent.

Another option is using the shotserver and shotfactory projects used for [browsershots.org](http://www.browsershots.org/). They can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/browsershots/files/), though I'm not sure if there's a .NET API for it.

Comment: Kwiboo (http://www.kwiboo.com/Products/Web-Snapshot) have a similar product that you can use as a web service to get the images.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is really possible only using C#. That is because C#, or the .NET framework for that matter, don't offer any kind of HTML markup rendering capabilities. The closest you can get - in my opinion - would be to use a WebBrowser control and then try to somehow capture it's graphical output (which would be the rendered page).

The other way to do it would be to look for a .NET component that might do what you want.. Although I don't know of any that do.